# "All of us deserve" or "all of us deserves" or "all of us deserved"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

As in "all of us deserve to be free." Assuming "all of us" refers to those who are dead and alive. So should we use "deserve" or "deserves" or "deserved?"

Comment: Do we deserve to be free at the time of the statement or simply at some point before that? Are the dead considered to be free or not?

Comment: Before that. So yes the dead deserved to be free too (even if we don't know if they did live freely).

Comment: "All of us" is plural and second person so 'deserves' (the third person singular present tense of the verb) is incorrect on two counts whatever is intended. It would only be appropriate if we said "One of us deserves to be free" which is singular. Because the individual is  not specified so it may or may not be the speaker who deserves freedom the third person would be correct in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general principle, and so would be declared as:

> All of us deserve to be free.

The exception would be if you were referring to freedom at a specific point in time in the past; in that case, at that point in time:

> All of us deserved to be free.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are too basic for a site aimed at linguists, and/or that lack reasonable basic research. Supported (by linked and attributed plausible references) answers are required for on-topic questions.